# how to set json data to select box using angular2

Tags: angular

## json data

```
{ "d": "[{\"batch\":\"5\",\"term\":\"TERM V\",\"section\":\"Section I\"},{\"batch\":\"5\",\"term\":\"TERM VI\",\"section\":\"Section I\"},{\"batch\":\"5\",\"term\":\"TERM VII\",\"section\":\"Section I\"},{\"batch\":\"6\",\"term\":\"TERM I\",\"section\":\"Section I\"},{\"batch\":\"6\",\"term\":\"TERM II\",\"section\":\"Section I\"}]" }
```

## Service

```
getwithParamter()    
{
  let params = {program: 'pravin'};
  this.headers = new Headers();
  this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  //this.headers.append('Parameter',  params);
  let options = new RequestOptions({
                method: RequestMethod.Post,
                url: "AttendanceMast.aspx/getBatch",                   
                headers: this.headers,
                body:{program: 'IFDM',location:'Pune',createdby:'ifdmpune'}
                });

  return this._http.request(new Request(options)).retry(2)
             .map((response: Response) =>  JSON.parse(response.text()))
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + data))
            .catch(this.handleError);                  

 }
```

## ts file

```
  this.dataService.getwithParamter().subscribe(
  tradeshows => this.getwithparamter = tradeshows,
  error => console.error('Error: ' + error)
);
```

## html

```
 Batch : <select  [(ngModel)]="sel_batch"  > <option >Select Batch</option>
                   <option *ngFor="let item of  getwithparamter   ">{{item.batch}}</option>
```

**Question**

I want to set `batch` from `json data` to `select box` see json data above this comes from  `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` how to convert normal array which access by `ngFor`

how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOT TESTED CODE**: You could try this: first parse the JSON like so:

ts:

```
  something: any;

  this.dataService.getwithParamter().subscribe(
    tradeshows => { 
      this.something = tradeshows
      this.getwithparameter = JSON.parse(this.something.d)
  });
```

and view:

```
<option *ngFor="let item of getwithparamter">{{item.batch}}</option>
```

**OR** in your html-view you could try:

```
  <option *ngFor="let item of getwithparamter.d">{{item.batch}}</option>
```

ts:

```
  this.dataService.getwithParamter().subscribe(
    tradeshows => { 
      this.getwithparameter = tradeshows
  });
```

As said, this is not tested, let me know if either works!

Comment: it works fine thanks  but related filter function not working showing error like ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined when I tried like <option *ngFor="let item of  getwithparamter | filterPipe: [];   ">{{item.batch}}</option>

Comment: I felt that may be filter calls before getwithparamter retrieve data Is there  any idea to call filter after retrieve data  in variable

Comment: Yeah, it's probably the issue - that the pipe tries to filter before data is retrieved. You could try and add an `*ngIf` there, it might solve the issue: `<select *ngIf="getwithparameter"  [(ngModel)]="sel_batch"  >`